# The view 'Index' or its master was not found when i ran my project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

this is the controller

```
namespace DemoforTesting.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        DefaultConnection db = new DefaultConnection();

        // GET: Product
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var products = db.Products.ToString();
            return View(products);    
        }

        // GET: Product/Details/5
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Product/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Product/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here    
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Product/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Product/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here    
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Product/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Product/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here    
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my view is

```
@model IEnumerable<OnLineShoppingCart.Models.Product>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Prod_Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Unit_Price)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ListPrice)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Qty_on_Stock)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Prod_Description)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Prod_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Unit_Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ListPrice)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qty_on_Stock)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Prod_Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ProductId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ProductId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ProductId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the error below  and i tried everything and ran out ideas

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The view 'SELECT 
   [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
   [Extent1].[Prod_Name] AS [Prod_Name], 
   [Extent1].[Unit_Price] AS [Unit_Price], 
   [Extent1].[ListPrice] AS [ListPrice], 
   [Extent1].[Qty_on_Stock] AS [Qty_on_Stock], 
   [Extent1].[Prod_Description] AS [Prod_Description]
   FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Product/SELECT 
   [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
   [Extent1].[Prod_Name] AS [Prod_Name], 
   [Extent1].[Unit_Price] AS [Unit_Price], `enter code here
   [Extent1].[ListPrice] AS [ListPrice], 
   [Extent1].[Qty_on_Stock] AS [Qty_on_Stock], 
   [Extent1].[Prod_Description] AS [Prod_Description]
   FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1].aspx
```

I have right clicked on the Index method and created the view and still get this error can someone  help me please I am new to MVC

Answer (score 2):

MVC is failing to find the appropriate view as you're passing the wrong object to your view. At present, '`products`' is just a string representation of `db.Products`, whereas your index view wants an `IEnumerable<Product>`

Change

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var products = db.Products.ToString();
            return View(products);

        }
```

To

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var products = db.Products.ToList(); //Or some other IENUM
            return View(products);

        }
```